# Properly Bring Down Active Node?

Tags: ros, c++, node, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently using ros::shutdown() to bring down a node that I need to kill in c++.  I'm fairly certain this is bad as the node fails ungracefully and does not seem to release all of its resources. Is there a better method?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221240/properly-bring-down-active-node?/) by [davelkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23120/davelkan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Likely what you want to do is create a custom SIGINT handler that releases whatever resources are not properly being released. This function will then get called whenever your node receives the SIGINT signal (e.g. when someone presses Ctrl+C) or when you call `ros::shutdown()`. A simple example is on the [roscpp Initialization and Shutdown](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Custom_SIGINT_Handler) page. Also check out [this question/answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/27655/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-stuff-before-a-node-is-shutdown/).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2